# kineticjs drag & drop - no release inconsistency

Tags: drag-and-drop, kineticjs

First of all drag and drop works correctly in my stages in version 4.3.0, so I just want to understand why I get the following problem with 4.3.3.

I have three stages. One sits in a container in a document in an iframe. The others sit in containers in the iframe's parent document, one displaying a complex layout of shapes and the other a single simple shape for testing. The document in the iframe which controls all the action has a viewfinder overlay that drags and drops correctly. However the shapes in the layout and test stages do not release on mouseup.

Any idea about what's going on would be appreciated ... I like to try and keep up to date.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let me explain how I found an answer by first amending the structure. There is a holding file which contains shared files and two iframes - one for a machine-like index and one for a display each with its own scripts. The main shared file is nameset.json which lists all the objects and their key/value couplets. These are sent to 'fill out' the machine and display frameworks. I thought I could do the same with the Kinetic Global object, referring to the Global.stages array. It seems obvious now that each of the iframes needs its own Kinetic link (rather than pointer) and these need to be used to marry machine/display interactions like the map shown here. Anyway all the dragging and dropping works smoothly as promoted. Thanks for that!

Will mark as answered but if anyone has any comments would be pleased to read them.

[image: nameset map device]

Answer (score 0):

Well, since I can't see any of your code I can only help so much, try doing the following.

For each shape that you have, add this attribute:

```
  dragOnTop: false
```

example:

```
  Kinetic.Rect({
      fill: 'blue',
      dragOnTop: false
  });
```

Comment: Otherwise, check your error console (Ctrl+Shift+J in firefox), the only other reason it would not release is if your code is breaking at some point and so all the logic goes out the window.

Comment: I don't think the code can be the problem because firstly it is the same for both versions and both locations and secondly both the overlay and test shapes are just basic .Rect s. Like you I thought it maybe new things that affect the layers but it doesn't seem to be that. The Chrome console doesn't offer any clues.

Comment: well, unless you have some code to show, then people can't really help you

Comment: Sorry I don't mean to be off hand but the code in both versions & locations is just like you show but with x, y, width, height, draggable:true. The only culprit I can think of is this:`sandbox = "allow-same-origin allow-scripts"` in the iframe but there again ...