# kineticjs chrome fill not working

Tags: google-chrome, kineticjs

Automatic Chrome update 26.0.1410.43m has something new that stops fill on my KineticJS shapes - also on the tutorial shapes I am relieved to see - http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/kineticjs/html5-canvas-kineticjs-rect-tutorial/

Does anyone know anything about this?

Comment: OK it now works in version 4.4 but not earlier versions as far as I can tell

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems I should mark this as answered, although the question of backward compatibility is of concern if you want to use Chrome and Kinectjs for non-trivial purposes.

However it forced me to solve another problem of my own making - see [kineticjs drag & drop - no release inconsistency](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15158768/kineticjs-drag-drop-no-release-inconsistency) so I am thankful for that!

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem, updating to the latest version of kineticJs solved my problem.
Note: I was using Kinetic 4.3.1 and updated to 4.4.0.

Comment: +1 It appears that a recent release of Chrome has broken KineticJS fills for versions 4.3.1 and below.  Upgrading to a newer version of KineticJS will solve the problem.